# Mismatch between 2.69 and 2.72 interfaces for Video Sequence Editor window

Tags: video-sequence-editor, windows

In the 2.69-based tutorial I am following, this is the interface shown for the Properties panel of the Video Sequence Editor set to Preview:

[image]

In the 2.72 version I am using on Windows 7, this is what I get for the same:

[image]

How can I get my version to match the tutorial?

Also, what setting in the Video Sequence Editor controls Preview vs Sequencer sub-views?

Comment: That would be a bug, or you dragged the `N` menu too far to the left, so that it now fills the whole window. Try hovering over it and pressing the `N` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.  Click on the "Current editor type for this area" icon (see picture below) and select "Properties" from the menu that comes up.  The display will change to the window type shown in the tutorial above.

[image]

Here's a detailed capture of the resulting new Properties window:

[image]

(Blender... powerful software, but what a learning curve!)